# Jenkins Pipeline and jboss deploy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently using Jenkins `FreeStyle Project` in my project,trying to migrate to Jenkins Pipeline, but I'm facing some issues:

1) I need to commit jenkinsfile in my project, but my deploy phase is just copy from target/project.war to jboss deployment folder, as shown below:

```
stage('Deploy') { 
            steps {
                sh 'cp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/project.war /opt/jboss/standalone/deployment/project.war'
            }
        }
```

**The problem**: currently the path is fixed and tomorrow if a change occurs and there is a need to deploy to another machine, An update should be made to the source code which should be avoided. In `FreeStyle project` i just update the JOB and everything works.

2) The project has 3 modules. The `FreeStyle project` was configured so that **JOB A** will call **JOB B** on finish. In pipeline how can this order be achieved:
   - Start **JOB A --> JOB B -->  JOB C.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following into your script

1.Issue with copying:

- Firstly, you avoid using the actual path(Location of file in workspace) to a
  relative Path i.e.  using project/*.war or **/*.war it will take it
  from the workspace itself.
- Second, Coming to the issue that you have
  to change the target location like you said you have to change it
  `FreeStyle Project` :) so you have to change it in the
  JenkinsFile also :)

2.To call other jobs in your pipeline and the following

```
 build job: 'Job2', parameters: [
              new org.jvnet.jenkins.plugins.nodelabelparameter.NodeParameterValue
                  ("TARGET_NODE", "description", nodeName)
          ]
```

If it does not have any parameter remove that section out.

There is something called Jenkins workflow which provides more power and control if your interested in it, you can look it up here https://dzone.com/refcardz/continuous-delivery-with-jenkins-workflow?chapter=1

Answer (score 1):

*you can use sshPulissher:send build artifacts over ssh*
[image]

[image]
add this code in your jenkins pipeline
[image]
and configure your sshServer in manage jenkins
[image]
finally your war is transfert in your destination

[image]